# reusable GetUserID function

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, user, clientpeoplepicker

I've some peoplepicker in sharepoint page and i need to get the user value of each one. 
I've used this [page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/use-the-client-side-people-picker-control-in-sharepoint-hosted-sharepoint-add-in) code to create the pickers. The script in the page retrieve the user id of a Picker control and put it into a div section using this function:

```
function getUserId(loginName) {
 var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
 this.user = context.get_web().ensureUser(loginName);
 context.load(this.user);
 context.executeQueryAsync(
 Function.createDelegate(null, ensureUserSuccess),
 Function.createDelegate(null, onFail));

 }
 function ensureUserSuccess() {

    $('#userTemp').html(this.user.get_id());
 }
 function onFail(sender, args) {
 alert('Query failed. Error: ' + args.get_message());
 }
```

There is a way to make this function reusable? Something like:

```
var FirstUserId  = getUserID('superman@superheroes.com');

var SecondUserId  = getUserID('batman@superheroes.com');
```

Thanks to everybody
Marco

Answer (score 0):

```
   **Your function should look like this**

     function getUserId(loginName) {
           //Declare your deferred object here  
            var deferred=$.Deferred(); 

            var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
            user = context.get_web().ensureUser(loginName);
            context.load(user);
            context.executeQueryAsync(
            Function.createDelegate(null, ensureUserSuccess),
            Function.createDelegate(null, onFail));

           function ensureUserSuccess() {
             //Resolve your object here  
             deferred.resolve(this.user.get_id()); 
           }


           function onFail(sender, args) {
             //Reject your object here  
             console.log('An error occured while retrieving list items:' + args.get_message());
             deferred.reject(this.user.get_id());  
          }  

         //Return your Promise Object  
         return deferred.promise(); 
   }
```

**Call function:**

$('#userTemp').html(getUserID('superman@superheroes.com'))

[REFERENCE](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/sharepoint-2013-implement-deferred-and-promise-object-in-javascript-asynchronous/)